# Is there a way to read previously enqueued messages in ActiveMQ using spark structured streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, activemq-classic, spark-structured-streaming

I have a producer which is sending messages to a topic of ActiveMQ and a client with following properties:

```
val optionsMap: Map[String, String] =
      Map[String, String]("brokerUrl" -> brokerUrl,
                          "topic" -> topicName, 
                          "persistence" -> "memory", 
                          "username" -> username, 
                          "password" -> password, 
                          "clientId" -> "something")
```

Now when my client application is not running and I send a message to the `ActiveMQ topic` the number of the `Enqueued Messages` increase by one and the count of the `Dequeued Messages` remain the same.
But as soon as I start my client, the number of `Dequeued Messages` become equal to the number of `Enqueued Messages` though my client application does not produce any output. How to fix this? I want my client application to output all the previously enqueued messages.

Answer (score -1):

Unless you are sending to a Topic that has an registered durable subscription the broker will discard all sent messages immediately as that is what a Topic is defined to do.  Only active Topic subscribers or durable subscriptions will receive messages sent to a Topic.

Comment: I am specifying a `clientId`, won't that make my subscriber durable?

Comment: No, and of course on the producer side that wouldn't work anyway.  The subscriber would have had to subscribe previously with a subscription name and a client id to create a durable subscription.

Comment: can you please point out how I can create a durable subscription in spark-structured-streaming... I mean I already have a clientId defined, how can I define the subscription name?